# How to report spam that appeared in Messages on iPhone marked "Text Message" & thus sent via carrier (e.g. AT&T) NOT Apple, & NOT from a phone #?

Tags: ios, messages, sms, cellular-carriers, spam

How do I report spam **like this**, which appeared in Messages on my iPhone? My carrier is AT&T. As I understand it, we can tell from the screen shot (because of the "Text Message") that my carrier delivered the message via SMS, not over Apple's secure iMessage protocol.  Which means this is a very different situation from [Spam on iMessage - What are my options?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351754/spam-on-imessage-what-are-my-options?rq=1). [image: Screen shot] (I think the originator can have whatever email addresses they want appear both above and in the text "Text Message" - they could easily have been, and likely are, forged - the email addresses ending in .ec and .com.)

I've had no success getting cooperation from AT&T.  Just stonewalling and deception.     And the volume is going up.

Comment: Reporting of SMS spam is carrier-dependent, so you might just consult their FAQ or contact them so see how to proceed here

Comment: I lengthened the title because it was attracting incorrect answers.

Comment: I'd take that as an answer. nohillside - well, if AT&T provides an answer.  I'll reach out.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing is almost impossible to block because, as you pointed out, the e-mail address is almost always forged.  I have hundreds of e-mails blocked on my account.  That being said...

How to block someone via the Messages on the iPhone or iPad

- Launch the Messages app from the Home screen of your iPhone or iPad.
- Tap the conversation of the person you're trying to block.
- Tap the info button in the top right corner.
- Tap the name of the contact.
- Tap Block Caller. ...
- Tap Block Contact.

This is courtesy of https://www.imore.com/how-mute-block-and-report-imessage-spam-iphone-and-ipad

Or...

> How do I stop spam texts AT&T?
>
> To report a spam SMS message received on your iPhone, you can forward the text to the number SPAM (7726). AT&T will reply with a text asking for the phone number of the person who sent the spam text message. Reply with the phone number and that's it.
>
> To block a specific email address
>
> Sign in to your AT&T Mobility account and create a Message Preferences account. Add email addresses to the block list by replying to the spam text with BLOCK in the reply message.

From... https://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/971823

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  

I think your first answer is wrong:  As I said, this is NOT iMessage spam - because the text "Text Message" is there.  I don't see you providing any reason to think otherwise.  Also, blocking isn't reporting.

Your second answer appears to wrong too, as the message is not from a phone #, and a report won't be accepted without one.  

I guess I could block it but again, blocking isn't reporting.

Comment: Again all of this is really for not because the address is almost always forged to begin with.  So it's not a solution that works in the first place.

Comment: The source IP can't be forged.  So a source IP in AT&T logs would show where it's *really* from.

Comment: Usually they come from Zombie bot networks so blocking the IP address is complicated.  They do have some filtering in place but in order to try to avoid people working around the tools in place they don't talk about it.

Comment: I just got two messages this week from political groups trying to sway my vote.  I never signed up for that shit and its from both parties republicans and democrats they also refer to me by name so apparently my text message number is for sale.  It's a shitty world we live in.

Comment: These days, a trivial server configuration setting is all that's needed to avoid spam from Zombie bot network IPs.  AT&T is grossly negligent IF they're not doing that.  Kind of like Napster - guilty of criminal facilitation.  But I see no evidence they're not doing that.