# What are the various ways I can stop getting iMessage spam notifications on my desktop besides turning off iMessages on my iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, ios, notifications

I just got a desktop notification on my MacBook that seems like spam. This is remarkable because I've never got a notification from anything other than my macOS notification before. I don't use non-OS notifications and don't want them.

Viewing in messages it is a "stock tip" in a foreign language and says:

> iMessage with xxxxx@hotmail.com

where "xxxxxx" is a placeholder.

A few months ago I'd sent a single iMessage by accident on my iPhone (not my laptop), I'd forgotten to turn it off after getting a new iPhone. I don't want to debate my personal preferences here, but I would like to know if turning off iMessage is the only way to block spam notifications like this. (I will turn of iMessage irregardless)

**notes:**

1. I have BlueTooth turned on because of my Apple Watch and my phone is also connected via USB to my laptop for hotspotting.
2. The message shows up in Messages on my iPhone as well, but for some reason there was no new message notification that I could see in the phone.
3. I do not have iMessages on my laptop (as far as I know)
4. iOS 15.3.1 and macOS 10.15.7

---

For background:

- [When does Messages message via iMessage vs. SMS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/375860/143729)
- [How can I ensure or force a message I'm composing to go via SMS on my iPhone 6 in iOS 12?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/375873/143729)
- [Stop my iPhone from receiving screen shots and other images sent via SMS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/383801/143729)
- [How to report spam that appeared in Messages on iPhone marked "Text Message" & thus sent via carrier (e.g. AT&T) NOT Apple, & NOT from a phone #?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/365709/143729) "This kind of thing is almost impossible to block because, as you pointed out, the e-mail address is almost always forged. I have hundreds of e-mails blocked on my account..."

Comment: An iMessage doesn't have to be sent to a phone#, it can be sent to an email address. You can check your "to be reached at" IDs in iMessage preferences, in the iMessage tab, and maybe adjust these to avoid the spam.

Comment: @Scot you mean iMessage tab on my phone correct? As mentioned in item #3 I don't have the iMessages app on my laptop as far as I can tell, which is one of the reasons that I was surprised to get a notification on my laptop. I did have gmail open in a tab of my Chrome browser on my laptop at the time, but I don't think that could be related (I'll add that to the question)

Comment: Interesting - you don't have the app entitled "Messages" (which is used for iMessage) on your Mac?

Comment: Yes I have Messages, I thought that iMessages was a separate app for macOS. Okay I'll go check. Thanks! **update:** Yes I see what happened. I recently got my first Apple ID (for reference see this [long comment chain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407112/143729)) and Apple decided to automatically add my personal email address to the list of "you can be reached at" without asking me. But I still don't understand why an iMessage to my phone makes a notification on my laptop's desktop and how I can stop that besides turning off iMessages on my phone.

Comment: This message may not have been sent to your phone, or your desktop, but instead to an email address. In any case - you can turn off notifications from unknown contacts in the General tab in Message Preferences within Messages on your Mac. Presumably the spam is from people who are not in your contact list.

Comment: @Scot It shows up in messages on my phone as well and does not appear in my Apple ID-associated email inbox nor spam folder, so I will *guess* that it was sent to my phone number. My one accidental iMessage was sent to someone who will have lots of international connections and may have very bad security hygiene so I'm gonna guess that that's the origin. Here's what I have now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNkE7.png I've just turned off "enable this account" but not sure if that's the right thing to do. You are more than welcome to post as an answer rather than another comment. *Thanks!*

Comment: Done. Hopefully that is helpful for you... I think the method you used shown in the picture should also eradicate the spam, but you will see!

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to turn off **all** notifications for Messages.app, you can do so in System Preferences - Notifications & Focus - Messages. Turn off "Allow Notifications."

Your phone may have nothing to do with this - one can send an iMessage (which is distinct from an EMail) to an Email address. You can check the locations that Messages.app (on your Mac) is "listening" on within Messages.app preferences, in the iMessage tab, and adjust these as needed to help stop the spam messages from coming through.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed to know.